# how to handle checked checkbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

in normal html form, you submit a form and you have access to array of check box in server side , but in angular there is no form post , and we have view model , what we have to do is to post Id of selected entities to server side method, here is how normally handle  selected check box for batch operation

here is my check box in ng-repeat loop

```
     <tr  ng-repeat="meeting in vm.meetings" class="odd gradeX">
         <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable icheck" ng-click="vm.selectMeeting(meeting)"/>
        </td>
```

and here is my function in angularjs controller

```
 function selectMeeting(meeting) {
        var index = -1;

//check to see if user has check or uncheckd the check box 
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.meetingSelected.length; i++) {

            if (vm.meetingSelected[i].indexOf(meeting.id) > -1) {
                index = i;
            }

        }
//if checked add it to vm.meetingSelected array
        if (index == -1) {
            vm.meetingSelected.push(meeting.id)
        }


//if unchecked remove it form   vm.meetingSelected array
        else {
            vm.meetingSelected.splice(index, 1);
        }

    }
```

i Dont like this code actully , i think there should be better way to select checked check box in angularjs.

any suggestion for better way to handle check box in angularjs ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ngModel` with checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.meetingSelected[$index]" />
```

You can pass in `$index`, or any object that keeps track of your `ngRepeat`.  It all depends on context.

Perhaps....

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.meetingSelected[meeting.name]" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.meetingSelected[meeting.id]" />
```

So when you're ready to process your model:

```
//only grab the selected meetings === true
for(var key in vm.meetingSelected) {
    if(vm.meetingSelected[key] === true)
        mySelectedMeetings.push(vm.meetingSelected[key]);
}
```

Or.... pass the whole thing and let your backend take care of grabbing only the `true` selected meetings.

Comment: this doesn't work because it doesnt remove selected meeting from vm.meetingSelected when user uncheck the check box, it just set its value to false

Comment: $index ? i want to pass if id of selected meeting .

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: See edit.  You can pass in anything you like.  It all depends on context.

Comment: this is fine solution